# Android Studio - Kotlin - Add a small google map that is clickable

Tags: android, api, dictionary, kotlin

I've built my app layout and it's all looking good to me about where my things will go. I'll put a screenshot of the one fragment in which I want to place a small google map API.

I want the google map in the button which says "MAP". I'm fairly new to android development and would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this and/or send me links to the videos that talk about exactly what I want because everything that I've tried searching for is either not necessary or not what I want.

Here's my page;
[image]

I want to add a map to the 'MAP' button that is clickable and will take me to google maps or if that's not considered 'API', I want it to become full screen. I'd prefer if it takes me to google maps though.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The basic steps for adding a map are:

1. You need to set up your API key and Gradle dependencies.
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config
2. Add a Fragment object to the Activity that will handle the map. The easiest way to do this is to add a  element to the layout file for the Activity.
3. Implement the OnMapReadyCallback interface and use the onMapReady(GoogleMap) callback method to get a handle to the GoogleMap object. The GoogleMap object is the internal representation of the map itself. To set the view options for a map, you modify its GoogleMap object.
4. Call getMapAsync() on the fragment to register the callback.

Please go through this link to get you started: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map

Comment: Also check this one: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/current-place-tutorial

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28323752)

Comment: Please check the edited answer. Thanks for this:)